# Why does the database access time change?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-3.5

For one of my applications, I'm running SQL Server 2005, and I'm running it on localhost. When I'm accessing it though the application it takes it 1-10 seconds to start showing data if I'm accessing it on localhost. However, when I move away from localhost and access it from another computer on the network, the access time is around one second.

Why is this, and how can I correct this so I can have the same access time on localhost?

**Connection String:** `Data Source=THESTUDIO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RentalEase;Integrated Security=True`

Quering using Typed Datasets (mostly)

When loading a form, I found Visual Studio queried the database with the same query multiple times. Although from what I understand, the database would respond with the cached version of the query. However, I did find that the application (from winform's databinding features) was executing this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [tblTenant] SET [TenantStatusID] = @TenantStatusID, [PropertyID] = @PropertyID, [UnitID] = @UnitID, [TenantName] = @TenantName, [Sex] = @Sex, [BirthDate] = @BirthDate, [SSNO] = @SSNO, [CoTenant1] = @CoTenant1, [CoTenant1Sex] = @CoTenant1Sex, [CoTenant1BirthDate] = @CoTenant1BirthDate, [CoTenant1SSNO] = @CoTenant1SSNO, [CoTenant2] = @CoTenant2, [CoTenant2Sex] = @CoTenant2Sex, [CoTenant2BirthDate] = @CoTenant2BirthDate, [CoTenant2SSNO] = @CoTenant2SSNO, [CoTenant3] = @CoTenant3, [CoTenant3Sex] = @CoTenant3Sex, [CoTenant3BirthDate] = @CoTenant3BirthDate, [CoTenant3SSNO] = @CoTenant3SSNO, [CarColor] = @CarColor, [CarModel] = @CarModel, [CarYear] = @CarYear, [CarState] = @CarState, [CarPlateNumber] = @CarPlateNumber, [Memo] = @Memo, [Address1] = @Address1, [Address2] = @Address2, [Address3] = @Address3, [Address4] = @Address4, [Phone] = @Phone, [ReferBy] = @ReferBy, [BeginDate] = @BeginDate, [NoticeGiven] = @NoticeGiven, [LeaseMonth2Month] = @LeaseMonth2Month, [LeaseEnds] = @LeaseEnds, [DepositPaid] = @DepositPaid, [DepositRefundable] = @DepositRefundable, [RefundMemo] = @RefundMemo, [RentDueDay] = @RentDueDay, [Charge1] = @Charge1, [Charge1Amount] = @Charge1Amount, [Charge2] = @Charge2, [Charge2Amount] = @Charge2Amount, [Charge3] = @Charge3, [Charge3Amount] = @Charge3Amount, [Charge4] = @Charge4, [Charge4Amount] = @Charge4Amount WHERE (([ID] = @Original_ID) AND ([TenantStatusID] = @Original_TenantStatusID) AND ((@IsNull_PropertyID = 1 AND [PropertyID] IS NULL) OR ([PropertyID] = @Original_PropertyID)) AND ((@IsNull_UnitID = 1 AND [UnitID] IS NULL) OR ([UnitID] = @Original_UnitID)) AND ((@IsNull_TenantName = 1 AND [TenantName] IS NULL) OR ([TenantName] = @Original_TenantName)) AND ((@IsNull_Sex = 1 AND [Sex] IS NULL) OR ([Sex] = @Original_Sex)) AND ((@IsNull_BirthDate = 1 AND [BirthDate] IS NULL) OR ([BirthDate] = @Original_BirthDate)) AND ((@IsNull_SSNO = 1 AND [SSNO] IS NULL) OR ([SSNO] = @Original_SSNO)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant1 = 1 AND [CoTenant1] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant1] = @Original_CoTenant1)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant1Sex = 1 AND [CoTenant1Sex] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant1Sex] = @Original_CoTenant1Sex)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant1BirthDate = 1 AND [CoTenant1BirthDate] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant1BirthDate] = @Original_CoTenant1BirthDate)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant1SSNO = 1 AND [CoTenant1SSNO] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant1SSNO] = @Original_CoTenant1SSNO)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant2 = 1 AND [CoTenant2] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant2] = @Original_CoTenant2)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant2Sex = 1 AND [CoTenant2Sex] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant2Sex] = @Original_CoTenant2Sex)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant2BirthDate = 1 AND [CoTenant2BirthDate] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant2BirthDate] = @Original_CoTenant2BirthDate)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant2SSNO = 1 AND [CoTenant2SSNO] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant2SSNO] = @Original_CoTenant2SSNO)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant3 = 1 AND [CoTenant3] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant3] = @Original_CoTenant3)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant3Sex = 1 AND [CoTenant3Sex] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant3Sex] = @Original_CoTenant3Sex)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant3BirthDate = 1 AND [CoTenant3BirthDate] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant3BirthDate] = @Original_CoTenant3BirthDate)) AND ((@IsNull_CoTenant3SSNO = 1 AND [CoTenant3SSNO] IS NULL) OR ([CoTenant3SSNO] = @Original_CoTenant3SSNO)) AND ((@IsNull_CarColor = 1 AND [CarColor] IS NULL) OR ([CarColor] = @Original_CarColor)) AND ((@IsNull_CarModel = 1 AND [CarModel] IS NULL) OR ([CarModel] = @Original_CarModel)) AND ((@IsNull_CarYear = 1 AND [CarYear] IS NULL) OR ([CarYear] = @Original_CarYear)) AND ((@IsNull_CarState = 1 AND [CarState] IS NULL) OR ([CarState] = @Original_CarState)) AND ((@IsNull_CarPlateNumber = 1 AND [CarPlateNumber] IS NULL) OR ([CarPlateNumber] = @Original_CarPlateNumber)) AND ((@IsNull_Address1 = 1 AND [Address1] IS NULL) OR ([Address1] = @Original_Address1)) AND ((@IsNull_Address2 = 1 AND [Address2] IS NULL) OR ([Address2] = @Original_Address2)) AND ((@IsNull_Address3 = 1 AND [Address3] IS NULL) OR ([Address3] = @Original_Address3)) AND ((@IsNull_Address4 = 1 AND [Address4] IS NULL) OR ([Address4] = @Original_Address4)) AND ((@IsNull_Phone = 1 AND [Phone] IS NULL) OR ([Phone] = @Original_Phone)) AND ((@IsNull_ReferBy = 1 AND [ReferBy] IS NULL) OR ([ReferBy] = @Original_ReferBy)) AND ((@IsNull_BeginDate = 1 AND [BeginDate] IS NULL) OR ([BeginDate] = @Original_BeginDate)) AND ((@IsNull_NoticeGiven = 1 AND [NoticeGiven] IS NULL) OR ([NoticeGiven] = @Original_NoticeGiven)) AND ((@IsNull_LeaseMonth2Month = 1 AND [LeaseMonth2Month] IS NULL) OR ([LeaseMonth2Month] = @Original_LeaseMonth2Month)) AND ((@IsNull_LeaseEnds = 1 AND [LeaseEnds] IS NULL) OR ([LeaseEnds] = @Original_LeaseEnds)) AND ((@IsNull_DepositPaid = 1 AND [DepositPaid] IS NULL) OR ([DepositPaid] = @Original_DepositPaid)) AND ((@IsNull_DepositRefundable = 1 AND [DepositRefundable] IS NULL) OR ([DepositRefundable] = @Original_DepositRefundable)) AND ((@IsNull_RentDueDay = 1 AND [RentDueDay] IS NULL) OR ([RentDueDay] = @Original_RentDueDay)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge1 = 1 AND [Charge1] IS NULL) OR ([Charge1] = @Original_Charge1)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge1Amount = 1 AND [Charge1Amount] IS NULL) OR ([Charge1Amount] = @Original_Charge1Amount)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge2 = 1 AND [Charge2] IS NULL) OR ([Charge2] = @Original_Charge2)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge2Amount = 1 AND [Charge2Amount] IS NULL) OR ([Charge2Amount] = @Original_Charge2Amount)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge3 = 1 AND [Charge3] IS NULL) OR ([Charge3] = @Original_Charge3)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge3Amount = 1 AND [Charge3Amount] IS NULL) OR ([Charge3Amount] = @Original_Charge3Amount)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge4 = 1 AND [Charge4] IS NULL) OR ([Charge4] = @Original_Charge4)) AND ((@IsNull_Charge4Amount = 1 AND [Charge4Amount] IS NULL) OR ([Charge4Amount] = @Original_Charge4Amount)));
SELECT ID, TenantStatusID, PropertyID, UnitID, TenantName, Sex, BirthDate, SSNO, CoTenant1, CoTenant1Sex, CoTenant1BirthDate, CoTenant1SSNO, CoTenant2, CoTenant2Sex, CoTenant2BirthDate, CoTenant2SSNO, CoTenant3, CoTenant3Sex, CoTenant3BirthDate, CoTenant3SSNO, CarColor, CarModel, CarYear, CarState, CarPlateNumber, Memo, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Phone, ReferBy, BeginDate, NoticeGiven, LeaseMonth2Month, LeaseEnds, DepositPaid, DepositRefundable, RefundMemo, RentDueDay, Charge1, Charge1Amount, Charge2, Charge2Amount, Charge3, Charge3Amount, Charge4, Charge4Amount FROM tblTenant WHERE (ID = @ID)',N'@TenantStatusID int,@PropertyID int,@UnitID int,@TenantName nvarchar(4),@Sex nvarchar(1),@BirthDate datetime,@SSNO nvarchar(9),@CoTenant1 nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant1Sex nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant1BirthDate datetime,@CoTenant1SSNO nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant2 nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant2Sex nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant2BirthDate datetime,@CoTenant2SSNO nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant3 nvarchar(2),@CoTenant3Sex nvarchar(4000),@CoTenant3BirthDate datetime,@CoTenant3SSNO nvarchar(4000),@CarColor nvarchar(4000),@CarModel nvarchar(4000),@CarYear nvarchar(4000),@CarState nvarchar(4000),@CarPlateNumber nvarchar(7),@Memo nvarchar(4000),@Address1 nvarchar(10),@Address2 nvarchar(10),@Address3 nvarchar(10),@Address4 nvarchar(10),@Phone nvarchar(4000),@ReferBy nvarchar(9),@BeginDate datetime,@NoticeGiven datetime,@LeaseMonth2Month bit,@LeaseEnds datetime,@DepositPaid money,@DepositRefundable money,@RefundMemo nvarchar(4000),@RentDueDay nvarchar(4000),@Charge1 int,@Charge1Amount money,@Charge2 int,@Charge2Amount money,@Charge3 int,@Charge3Amount money,@Charge4 int,@Charge4Amount money,@Original_ID int,@Original_TenantStatusID int,@IsNull_PropertyID int,@Original_PropertyID int,@IsNull_UnitID int,@Original_UnitID int,@IsNull_TenantName int,@Original_TenantName nvarchar(4),@IsNull_Sex int,@Original_Sex nvarchar(1),@IsNull_BirthDate int,@Original_BirthDate datetime,@IsNull_SSNO int,@Original_SSNO nvarchar(9),@IsNull_CoTenant1 int,@Original_CoTenant1 nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant1Sex int,@Original_CoTenant1Sex nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant1BirthDate int,@Original_CoTenant1BirthDate datetime,@IsNull_CoTenant1SSNO int,@Original_CoTenant1SSNO nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant2 int,@Original_CoTenant2 nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant2Sex int,@Original_CoTenant2Sex nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant2BirthDate int,@Original_CoTenant2BirthDate datetime,@IsNull_CoTenant2SSNO int,@Original_CoTenant2SSNO nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant3 int,@Original_CoTenant3 nvarchar(2),@IsNull_CoTenant3Sex int,@Original_CoTenant3Sex nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CoTenant3BirthDate int,@Original_CoTenant3BirthDate datetime,@IsNull_CoTenant3SSNO int,@Original_CoTenant3SSNO nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CarColor int,@Original_CarColor nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CarModel int,@Original_CarModel nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CarYear int,@Original_CarYear nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CarState int,@Original_CarState nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_CarPlateNumber int,@Original_CarPlateNumber nvarchar(7),@IsNull_Address1 int,@Original_Address1 nvarchar(10),@IsNull_Address2 int,@Original_Address2 nvarchar(10),@IsNull_Address3 int,@Original_Address3 nvarchar(10),@IsNull_Address4 int,@Original_Address4 nvarchar(10),@IsNull_Phone int,@Original_Phone nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_ReferBy int,@Original_ReferBy nvarchar(9),@IsNull_BeginDate int,@Original_BeginDate datetime,@IsNull_NoticeGiven int,@Original_NoticeGiven datetime,@IsNull_LeaseMonth2Month int,@Original_LeaseMonth2Month bit,@IsNull_LeaseEnds int,@Original_LeaseEnds datetime,@IsNull_DepositPaid int,@Original_DepositPaid money,@IsNull_DepositRefundable int,@Original_DepositRefundable money,@IsNull_RentDueDay int,@Original_RentDueDay nvarchar(4000),@IsNull_Charge1 int,@Original_Charge1 int,@IsNull_Charge1Amount int,@Original_Charge1Amount money,@IsNull_Charge2 int,@Original_Charge2 int,@IsNull_Charge2Amount int,@Original_Charge2Amount money,@IsNull_Charge3 int,@Original_Charge3 int,@IsNull_Charge3Amount int,@Original_Charge3Amount money,@IsNull_Charge4 int,@Original_Charge4 int,@IsNull_Charge4Amount int,@Original_Charge4Amount money,@ID int',@TenantStatusID=1,@PropertyID=111,@UnitID=2175,@TenantName=N'Judy',@Sex=N'1',@BirthDate='Apr 29 1980  3:26:06:000PM',@SSNO=N'333333333',@CoTenant1=NULL,@CoTenant1Sex=NULL,@CoTenant1BirthDate=NULL,@CoTenant1SSNO=NULL,@CoTenant2=NULL,@CoTenant2Sex=NULL,@CoTenant2BirthDate=NULL,@CoTenant2SSNO=NULL,@CoTenant3=N'51',@CoTenant3Sex=NULL,@CoTenant3BirthDate=NULL,@CoTenant3SSNO=NULL,@CarColor=NULL,@CarModel=NULL,@CarYear=NULL,@CarState=NULL,@CarPlateNumber=N'001122B',@Memo=NULL,@Address1=N'blah line1',@Address2=N'blah line2',@Address3=N'blah line3',@Address4=N'blah line4',@Phone=NULL,@ReferBy=N'McDonalds',@BeginDate='May  6 2009  4:54:28:000PM',@NoticeGiven='May  6 2009 11:58:45:000AM',@LeaseMonth2Month=1,@LeaseEnds='May 21 2009 10:06:25:000AM',@DepositPaid=50.0000,@DepositRefundable=0.0000,@RefundMemo=NULL,@RentDueDay=NULL,@Charge1=6,@Charge1Amount=50.0000,@Charge2=49,@Charge2Amount=50.0000,@Charge3=45,@Charge3Amount=5.0000,@Charge4=47,@Charge4Amount=7.0000,@Original_ID=10,@Original_TenantStatusID=1,@IsNull_PropertyID=0,@Original_PropertyID=111,@IsNull_UnitID=0,@Original_UnitID=2175,@IsNull_TenantName=0,@Original_TenantName=N'Judy',@IsNull_Sex=0,@Original_Sex=N'1',@IsNull_BirthDate=0,@Original_BirthDate='Apr 29 1980  3:26:06:000PM',@IsNull_SSNO=0,@Original_SSNO=N'333333333',@IsNull_CoTenant1=1,@Original_CoTenant1=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant1Sex=1,@Original_CoTenant1Sex=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant1BirthDate=1,@Original_CoTenant1BirthDate=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant1SSNO=1,@Original_CoTenant1SSNO=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant2=1,@Original_CoTenant2=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant2Sex=1,@Original_CoTenant2Sex=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant2BirthDate=1,@Original_CoTenant2BirthDate=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant2SSNO=1,@Original_CoTenant2SSNO=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant3=0,@Original_CoTenant3=N'51',@IsNull_CoTenant3Sex=1,@Original_CoTenant3Sex=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant3BirthDate=1,@Original_CoTenant3BirthDate=NULL,@IsNull_CoTenant3SSNO=1,@Original_CoTenant3SSNO=NULL,@IsNull_CarColor=1,@Original_CarColor=NULL,@IsNull_CarModel=1,@Original_CarModel=NULL,@IsNull_CarYear=1,@Original_CarYear=NULL,@IsNull_CarState=1,@Original_CarState=NULL,@IsNull_CarPlateNumber=0,@Original_CarPlateNumber=N'001122B',@IsNull_Address1=0,@Original_Address1=N'blah line1',@IsNull_Address2=0,@Original_Address2=N'blah line2',@IsNull_Address3=0,@Original_Address3=N'blah line3',@IsNull_Address4=0,@Original_Address4=N'blah line4',@IsNull_Phone=1,@Original_Phone=NULL,@IsNull_ReferBy=0,@Original_ReferBy=N'McDonalds',@IsNull_BeginDate=0,@Original_BeginDate='May  6 2009  4:54:28:000PM',@IsNull_NoticeGiven=0,@Original_NoticeGiven='May  6 2009 11:58:45:000AM',@IsNull_LeaseMonth2Month=0,@Original_LeaseMonth2Month=1,@IsNull_LeaseEnds=0,@Original_LeaseEnds='May 21 2009 10:06:25:000AM',@IsNull_DepositPaid=0,@Original_DepositPaid=50.0000,@IsNull_DepositRefundable=0,@Original_DepositRefundable=0.0000,@IsNull_RentDueDay=1,@Original_RentDueDay=NULL,@IsNull_Charge1=0,@Original_Charge1=6,@IsNull_Charge1Amount=0,@Original_Charge1Amount=50.0000,@IsNull_Charge2=0,@Original_Charge2=49,@IsNull_Charge2Amount=0,@Original_Charge2Amount=50.0000,@IsNull_Charge3=0,@Original_Charge3=45,@IsNull_Charge3Amount=0,@Original_Charge3Amount=5.0000,@IsNull_Charge4=0,@Original_Charge4=47,@IsNull_Charge4Amount=0,@Original_Charge4Amount=7.0000,@ID=10
```

At it is taking around a full second to complete. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach [Sql Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979207.aspx) to the server to see what exactly is going on, and if the Sql Statements are really identical.

If they are, and there's still a difference, perhaps one of the applications is using a different execution plan. Clean out the cache with:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

And check if it makes a difference.

Many other suggestions in this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801909/why-is-some-sql-query-much-slower-when-used-with-sqlcommand).

Comment: How can I attach an SQL Profiler to a C# winforms app?

Comment: You attach it to the database, not the app :)

Comment: That related post really isn't related, I'm executing the same queries, just from different machines.

Comment: The other post was executing the same query, but from a different environment.  I think many of the things there make sense, but up to you :)

Comment: I'm running the SQL Express 2005, I don't think I have access to a profiler.

Comment: Found a neat tool, AnjLab SqlProfiler, updating question

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the 10 seconds is the amount of time it takes for the (infrequently used) database on your local machine to be started. I haven't actually tried to fix that, but my first guess would be to try disabling the "Auto close" property for that database.

For a further description of the "Auto close" property, see [this exerpt from the book titled 'Designing SQL Server 2000 Databases for .NET Enterprise Servers'](http://books.google.ca/books?id=oAD7HVhOBOAC&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=sql+%22auto+close%22&source=bl&ots=JbMgeJz-3E&sig=XU7UmzyxRfO91LSrBwn5sFSm074&hl=en&ei=0gAbSs2jDYOyNMHxzY8P&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1).

Comment: Database is running all the time. This problem would affect remote connections too.

Comment: Try that changing that option on your local machine anyway: maybe your SQL server service is running but doesn't always have that database instance loaded.

Comment: You can see the option by starting SQL Management Studio, right-click on the database, select Properties, and then choose Options.

Comment: Even if that was causing the problem, remote connections would be affected by the same delay, so I seriously doubt this is it. I'll try it anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

What else is your local computer doing? How are you querying? I'd be surprised if the delay is in the database, unless other loaded applications are causing swapping.

Comment: question updated. I'm using the dev machine at the same time my co worker is connecting to it's database and his queries execute a lot faster than when I execute them on the dev machine

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the local machine and remote machines have different client network protocol settings. Eg. the local machine is configured to try shared-memory first then net-pipes then tcp, but the server is configured not to listen on shared memory (unusual, but possible). The remote machines are configured to try tcp directly so they hit jackpot from first try. Just a shot in the dark, w//o more information available.

You should analyze the problem first and determine where does the 10 second delay occur: at opening the connection, at running the query, at returning the result to the client etc.

Comment: Shared memory, named pipes and tcp/ip are enabled, only VIA is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It might be down to the specific communication protocols SQL Server is attempting to use on the local machine.

You need to post
- your connection string
- the protocols that are enabled on your server machine (from the SQL Server configuration manager).