# Why does this stored procedure execute quickly in Management Studio, but not in an application?

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset, sql-server-2005-express

I have this query as a stored procedure:

```
SELECT     ID
    FROM         dbo.tblRentalUnit
    WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT     1 AS Expr1
        FROM          dbo.tblTenant
        WHERE      (dbo.tblRentalUnit.ID = UnitID)))
```

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express, it executes in 16 ms. When I have it in a typed dataset auto-generated by Visual Studio 2008, it executes in 64,453 ms. More than a minute.

Estimated and Execution plan are like this:

```
Select [0%] <- Filter [1%] <- Merge Join (Left Outer Join) [28%] <- Index Scan [16%]
                                                                 <- Sort [43%] <- Clustered Index Scan [12%]
```

Why is this difference here, and how can I correct it?

Comment: If you need more information about the setup, please let me know!

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?

Comment: Probably something involving blue sky, green grass, and the sun rising in the east.

Comment: That's always a good reason...I guess.

Comment: I honestly don't know why that is getting down-votes; looks OK to me (although possibly a dup, but nobody has voted dup)... you might also want to read the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801909/

Comment: I saw that, that's where I got the 'SET ARITHABORT ON', which I commented on Mitch Wheat's answer. That still doesn't bring me up to the same speed as I have in SSMS, although it improved it by about 59 seconds, it's still executing lots and lots slower than SSMS. About 366 times slower.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an incorrectly cached query plan.

Are your indexes and statistics up to date?

BTW, if tblTenant.UnitId is a Foriegn Key into tblRentalUnit.ID
then your query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT ru.ID    
FROM         
    dbo.tblRentalUnit ru
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblTenant t ON ru.ID = t.UnitID
WHERE
    t.UnitID IS NULL
```

Comment: How do I check and see if my indexes and statistics are up to date? According to the properties of the database, they're auto-updated

Comment: Switching to this query and setting ARITHABORT ON; dropped the execution time down to 5859 ms in the application, but it still isn't the same as how it would execute in Management Studio

Comment: In SSMS take a look at the Estimated and Actual Execution plans for differences (maybe post here)

Comment: There is no difference between the two. I'll append it to my question though

Answer (score 0):

Did you flush the buffers before each test (from either client)? Make sure you are executing DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS and DBCC FREEPROCCACHE between each test.

Comment: Make sure it's not a production box! ;)

Comment: I did that, it's not a production box either :)

Answer (score 0):

Is tblRentalUnit.ID properly indexed?

Comment: yes it is. Everything is indexed, everything in this query acts only on indexes.

Comment: "Everything" being indexed could be part of the problem. How did you tune your indexes?