# Sql Query Execution Time difference between SSMS & SqlCommand

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-3.5, sqlcommand

I am executing one SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio (2008) and the same query using `SqlCommand` (.net 3.5) in C#.

In Management Studio the query executes in **1.6 minutes** to complete. The same query is taking **9 minutes** using `SqlCommand` in C#.

Why is the huge difference between SQL Server Management Studio & `SqlCommand`?

Please somebody help me in finding the solution in fixing the time difference.

Thanks in advance.

The query:

```
SELECT * INTO [target_table]
FROM [source_table] WHERE Group_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

This copies around 1 million rows into target_table & table contains 220 columns.

Comment: Hi Marc, thank for quick comment. I added the query in the question.

Comment: OK, do you need **all** the columns?? If not - **specify** which ones you really do need! Also: is there an index on `Group_ID` ?

Comment: yes I need all  the columns and the group_id included the index keys (composite primary key).

Comment: Hi , the below url can help; http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking what causes the difference between the two environments, I'm going to try to answer that question, and not the much bigger question of how to make copying 1,000,000 records faster.

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801909/why-is-some-sql-query-much-slower-when-used-with-sqlcommand?rq=1) provides a good guide to troubleshooting your situation.  If you're using the exact same command or stored procedure call and consistently get this difference in results, the most likely culprit is different SET options.

Try using the profiler to see what SET options are set when you execute the insert in SSMS.  Do the same thing with your C# routine.  Compare them and see what SSMS sets differently than ADO.NET does.

Comment: Thanks Ann, for the reply. I can at the url explaining in detail: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html