# Long running SP never ends using sqlCommand

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've got a quite expensive stored procedure in my SQL Server database. Launching it from the SQL Server Managment Studio requires some minutes. But I can't launch it via code using SqlCommand.

I've got this code:

```
spExecQuery = "EXEC [schema].[storedName]"
```

If I use this vb.NET snippet:

```
Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(spExecQuery, conn)
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The script ends with "Timeout expired" error. But if I do:

```
Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(spExecQuery, conn)
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The script never ends (it's running from at least 2 hours)... What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify first that it's a stored-procedure:

```
Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(spExecQuery, conn)
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

You could also use [`QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to let the method run asynchronously, then you don't need to wait until it has finished:

```
Public Shared Sub ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync()
    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        New Threading.WaitCallback(AddressOf ExecuteStoredProcedure)
        )
End Sub

Private Shared Sub ExecuteStoredProcedure(threadState As Object)
    Dim sw = New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Try
        ' add code or call of long running method here '
        Log.WriteInfo(String.Format("ExecuteStoredProcedure(async call) executed successfully, execution-time: {0}.", sw.Elapsed))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log.WriteError(String.Format("Exception in ExecuteStoredProcedure (async call), execution-time: {0}.", sw.Elapsed))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I've done as suggested, but in the meanwhile the script has ended. It took about 4 hours... So the real question is why so much difference between SSMS and the code I ran? Anyway, I hope the solution you provided will speed up the execution. I already running the SP in a different thread, but I'm inside a setup project, so it must finish before I allow to go to the next page... For now I'm allowing to skip the SP execution, because it would be a pain to wait for such a long time inside an installer...

Comment: @ufo: you have to use the profiler to see why there's such a great difference between ssms and `SqlCommand`. Maybe this helps also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801909/why-is-some-sql-query-much-slower-when-used-with-sqlcommand

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you specify the **CmdType**.

If still not working, try using the **SqlDataReader**

```
 cmd.Connection = conn
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
 cmd.CommandText = "proc_name"

 Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add the command type to your sqlcommand

```
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```