# Stored procedure is executing with different indexes when called via Entity Framework compared to SSMS

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, indexing, dynamic-sql

We have a stored procedure that executes dynamic sql via `sp_executesql`.

We have observed via the SQL Server profiler and looking at the execution plans the profiler shows that when this procedure is called via SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) it uses a good combination of indexes, therefore returning in 2 secs.

On the other hand, when we call this procedure via our .NET application (called via Entity Framework) - and exactly the same parameters are used compared to the call in SSMS - then SQL Server uses a much worse choice for the indexes.

And this behaviour is deterministic. Called via our app - bad index. Called via SSMS - good index.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be the case?

Many thanks.

**Update:**

The stored procedure call looks like this:
    `EXEC [schema].[sp] @a=123,@b=NULL`

The dynamic SQL inside the procedure is executed like this:

```
   `EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@a int, @b smallint',
    @a = @a,
    @b = @b`
```

Comment: Very interesting! Could you please include at least the SQL string that is being sent via .NET and what you type into SSMS?

Comment: @krillgar added code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: I focused two much on entity framework, but when I widened my search I found answers about ADO.NET using different settings on the connection, therefore using a different execution plan: [Why is some sql query much slower when used with SqlCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801909/why-is-some-sql-query-much-slower-when-used-with-sqlcommand)