# Behaviour difference between SqlCommand and SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I have had, more than once, the problem that a complex query, when executed through a `SqlCommand` from a .NET application, behaves differently performance-wise than a query that is executed in SSMS. When I encounter these issues, the `SqlCommand` is always slower than queries run in SSMS, against the same database. Most notable are execution times of 3 seconds vs 150 ms, and 30 seconds vs. 70 ms.

What issues does the `SqlCommand` have that make it slower than queries run in SSMS?

Comment: what is the command?, are you passing parameters?

Comment: You have to show something. Should we guess? Maybe parameter sniffing because you don't use `Paramaters.Add("@col", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value="foo"` but `AddWithValue("@col", "foo")`. Maybe because you have deadlocks that your application causes

Comment: Your question has been discussed on StackOverflow at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736638/sql-query-slow-in-net-application-but-instantaneous-in-sql-server-management-st) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801909/why-is-some-sql-query-much-slower-when-used-with-sqlcommand). There's is also a dedicated [article from Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), SQL MVP